# How can I separate a file with columns 1-7 of data into ONE column with all the data in order?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

For example, I have all of this data but i want it organized in a way such that the output file is purely numbers, with rows 1-7 corresponding to columns 1-7, then rows 8-14 corresponding to columns 1-7 on the second row, and etc.

Can I do this using awk?

Also

Example of data:

```
Total    31.6459262.4011 31.6463 31.6463  0.0006  0.0006  0.0007
Total     0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0008  0.0008
Total     0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008
Total     0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008
Total     0.0008  0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0006  0.0006  0.0006
Total     0.0005  0.0005  0.0004  0.0003  0.0003  0.0002  0.0001
Total     0.0001  0.0000 -0.0001 -0.0002 -0.0002 -0.0003 -0.0004
Total    -0.0005 -0.0006 -0.0007 -0.0008 -0.0009 -0.0010 -0.0011
Total    -0.0011 -0.0012 -0.0013 -0.0014 -0.0015 -0.0015 -0.0016
Total    -0.0016 -0.0017 -0.0018 -0.0018 -0.0018 -0.0019 -0.0019
Total    -0.0019 -0.0019 -0.0020 -0.0020 -0.0020 -0.0020 -0.0020
Total    -0.0019 -0.0019 -0.0019 -0.0019 -0.0018 -0.0018 -0.0018
Total    -0.0017 -0.0017 -0.0017 -0.0016 -0.0016 -0.0015 -0.0015
Total    -0.0014 -0.0014 -0.0013 -0.0012 -0.0012 -0.0011 -0.0011
Total    -0.0010 -0.0010 -0.0009 -0.0009 -0.0008 -0.0008 -0.0007
Total    31.6459262.4010 31.6461 31.6462  0.0006  0.0006  0.0006
Total     0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0007  0.0007
Total     0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008  0.0008
```

The output is lengthy to type, but it would consist of all these numbers arranged in one column without the four numbers that repeat every so often, 31.6459, 262.4010, 31.6461, and 31.6462. These four numbers are not always exactly the same, but they are certainly always greater than ~20. And they do repeat every 101 numbers.

Output:

```
0.0006
0.0006
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0005
0.0005
0.0004
0.0003
0.0003
0.0002
0.0001
0.0001
0.0000
-0.0001
-0.0002
-0.0002
-0.0003
-0.0004
-0.0005
-0.0006
-0.0007
-0.0008
-0.0009
-0.0010
-0.0011
-0.0011
-0.0012
-0.0013
-0.0014
-0.0015
-0.0015
-0.0016
-0.0016
-0.0017
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0017
-0.0017
-0.0017
-0.0016
-0.0016
-0.0015
-0.0015
-0.0014
-0.0014
-0.0013
-0.0012
-0.0012
-0.0011
-0.0011
-0.0010
-0.0010
-0.0009
-0.0009
-0.0008
-0.0008
-0.0007
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
```

Comment: What i meant was, I want my output file to be organized so that the first row of my input file is split into 7 rows of purely numbers, in this case, it would be:

4.0278
9.3880
4.0282
4.0288
etc..

Comment: Also, I am new to this site, sorry about the formatting, but how can I get the formatting to like the edit you did for my input file? Terminal-like, in other words

Comment: Can you please add the output you'd expect from your example data.

Comment: @rojomoke I edited it to include the output.

Comment: @EdMorton I fixed my input/output.

Answer (score 2):

There are PLENTY of numbers that repeat frequently in your data so we can't exclude the ones you mention based on them repeating so - do you want exclude numbers with value >= 20?

If so, this may be what you want using GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8"}
       {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<20) {sub(/^ +/,"",$i); print $i} }' file
0.0006
0.0006
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0005
0.0005
0.0004
0.0003
0.0003
0.0002
0.0001
0.0001
0.0000
-0.0001
-0.0002
-0.0002
-0.0003
-0.0004
-0.0005
-0.0006
-0.0007
-0.0008
-0.0009
-0.0010
-0.0011
-0.0011
-0.0012
-0.0013
-0.0014
-0.0015
-0.0015
-0.0016
-0.0016
-0.0017
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0017
-0.0017
-0.0017
-0.0016
-0.0016
-0.0015
-0.0015
-0.0014
-0.0014
-0.0013
-0.0012
-0.0012
-0.0011
-0.0011
-0.0010
-0.0010
-0.0009
-0.0009
-0.0008
-0.0008
-0.0007
0.0006
0.0006
0.0006
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0007
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
0.0008
```

I feel like you could have come up with a briefer example btw.

Comment: I seem to be missing some entries. I am going to edit my question with the new input that I am using, with a slightly different question as well

Comment: I do want the output to be in this same style as yours here though.

Comment: @DanielLuci If you change the number of fields in your source file, as your edit seems to have, you have to change the value of `i` in the for loop here.  By default `awk` will split on white space of any kind, so with your new input you'd want `i=2`, though it will not do quite what you want with the places where the numbers run into each other, since there is no space between them to split on